# How to I get all the checkins a user is tagged in using FQL

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-checkins

Using the graph api it's possible to do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins
```

But how am I supposed to do it with FQL?
I tried [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6861930/facebook-fql-get-all-checkins-me-is-tagged-in) which suggests:

```
SELECT message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
AND me() IN tagged_uids
```

but it doesn't return even a single result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, `IN` doesn't seem to work with `me()`. You have to first get the user id and assign this to a variable. This throws an OAuth exception:

```
SELECT message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid = me() OR me() IN tagged_ids
```

but if you set `[UserId]` to the current user's id, this works:

```
SELECT message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid = [UserId] OR [UserId] IN tagged_ids
```

You don't need to use the `friend` subquery. FQL will only return checkins that are visible to your user.

For this to work, make sure your `access_token` has both the `user_checkins` and `friends_checkins` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

@cpilko gave a solution, but I've found another one, so I am adding it here as a reference for whoever reach this page:

```
SELECT id FROM location_post WHERE ([UserId] IN tagged_uids OR author_uid=me()) AND strpos(type,"checkin")>=0
```